# How to list $PATH?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, path

When I `echo $PATH` 
I get: `home/x/bin:home/x/.local/bin:...:...` and on and on where each path is separated by `:`

When I `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'`
I get:

```
home/x/bin
home/x/.local/bin
...
...
```

Where very path is separated by a new line

So now I want to fit all of this into a variable (`$`) or a script so I can execute it and it lists the path by line, but it wont work:

I tried: `x=${echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'}`
but I get `-bash: ${echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'}: bad substitution`

I also tried a script where:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PATH > 11
sleep 1
bb=${`tr ':' '\n' < 11`}
echo $bb
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use bash's [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just studied on Parameter Expansion and everything makes so much sense now!!!!!!  In your question, `echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"` could you give me a couple more examples where the second `$` is implied or used?

Comment: Bash replaces `$'\n'` with a newline without using echo’s `-e` option. With echo’s `-e` option this is possible, too: `echo -e "${PATH//:/\n}"`

Answer (score 3):

you should use command substitution. Curly Braces is use for grouping $ for variable substitution. while for command substition you need backticks if you se bourn shell, but for bash you need brackets

```
# Wrong
x=${echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'}

# Right
x=$(echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n')
echo "$x"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however that will not work. as you can see in this image (http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=25k0vw9&s=9) which is my screenshot. I'm trying to list the $PATH

Comment: I suggest to use `echo "$x"`.

Comment: wrap the x in quotes, just as Cyrus said

Comment: Similarly, `echo "$PATH"` is going to behave better than `echo $PATH`, albeit in unusual niche cases. (Consider what happens if you have `IFS=/`, for instance).

Comment: BTW, the `/bin/sh` defined in POSIX since the 1992 revision of the specification is not Bourne shell but POSIX sh (Bourne is far older, 1970s-era), and supports `$()` rather than backticks alone.

Answer (score 2):

To expand @cyrus's Parameter Expansion idea, here's the alias version:

```
alias pathprint='echo "${PATH//:/$'"'"'\n'"'"'}"'
```

Need to use single quote `'` around the aliased command to prevent `$PATH` from being expanded while alias is defined.

Then, *escape* each single quote within command as:

```
' => ' + "'" + '
```

Stop previous quote `'`, add a single quote using double quotes `"'"`, followed by a single quote to resume quoting `'`.